# JAVA Xml Unmarshaller Null Pointer Exception (+ JavaFx, but I don't think it is relevant to my problem)

Tags: java, unmarshalling

thanks for your time, I've been programming in java for a while but i'm not studing computer science so I don't know lot of things, I'm learning on the way.

**Context**:
I'm following a tutorial (mainly about javafx: https://code.makery.ch/it/library/javafx-tutorial/part5/) to learn how to save and load data to/from an xml file. I'm programming a similiar application but not the same as the tutorial so if I have a problem I can't just look at what's different, however the code is still quite similar and I can compare them, in this case, doing so I couldn't find much of a difference between my "algorhitm" and the one used by the tutorial

**The Problem**:
When loading the data from the xml I get a Null Pointer Exception (see below "loadPersonDataFromFile" method) but I don't know what is causing it

Here I'm reporting some method and classes I think are relevant to the problem, if you need more let me know, and thank you again.

the "savePersonDataToFile" method works fine, here it is:

```
public void savePersonDataToFile(File file) {
    try {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext
                .newInstance(ItemListWrapper.class);
        Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        // Wrapping our person data.
        ItemListWrapper wrapper = new ItemListWrapper();
        wrapper.setPersons(itemData);

        // Marshalling and saving XML to the file.
        m.marshal(wrapper, file);

        // Save the file path to the registry.
        setPersonFilePath(file);
    } catch (Exception e) { // catches ANY exception
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
        alert.setTitle("Error");
        alert.setHeaderText("Could not save data");
        alert.setContentText("Could not save data to file:\n" + file.getPath());

        alert.showAndWait();
    }
}
```

and creates a xml which is correct (compared to the one created by the tutorial application)

but the "loadPersonDataFromFile" method does not, here you can see it:

```
public void loadPersonDataFromFile(File file) {
    try {
        System.out.print("1\n");
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext
                .newInstance(ItemListWrapper.class);
        Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
        
        System.out.print("2\n");
        System.out.print(String.valueOf(file.getPath()) + "\n");

        ItemListWrapper wrapper = (ItemListWrapper) um.unmarshal(file);
        
        System.out.print("3\n");
        
        List<Item> dataDue = wrapper.getItems();
        
        System.out.print("3.5\n");
        System.out.print(String.valueOf(dataDue) + "\n");
        
        String data = dataDue.get(0).getThing();
        System.out.print(data);

        itemData.clear();
        itemData.addAll(wrapper.getItems());
        
        System.out.print("4\n");

        // Save the file path to the registry.
        setPersonFilePath(file);
        
        System.out.print("5\n");


    } catch (Exception e) { // catches ANY exception
        System.out.print(e + "\n");
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
        alert.setTitle("Error");
        alert.setHeaderText("Could not load data");
        alert.setContentText("Could not load data from file:\n" + file.getPath());

        alert.showAndWait();
    }
    
}
```

the exception is given by this command (I added some Console output to find it):

```
ItemListWrapper wrapper = (ItemListWrapper) um.unmarshal(file);
```

File is not null and its path is correct.
The imported library for Unmarshaller is the correct one (same as the tutorial one).

ItemListWrapper is a class needed to save data into an xml:

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "items")
public class ItemListWrapper {

private List<Item> items;

@XmlElement(name = "item")
public List<Item> getItems() {
    return items;
}

public void setPersons(List<Item> items) {
    this.items = items;
}
}
```

while Item is the object type i'm trying to get from the xml.

Item Class:

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class Item 
{

private final StringProperty status;
private final StringProperty thing;

public Item() {
    this(null,null);
}

public Item(String status, String thing) {
    this.status = new SimpleStringProperty(status);
    this.thing = new SimpleStringProperty(thing);
}


public String getStatus()
{
    return status.get();
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status.set(status);
}

public StringProperty statusProperty()
{
    return status;
}


public String getThing()
{
    return thing.get();
}

public void setThing(String thing) {
    this.thing.set(thing);
}

public StringProperty thingProperty() {
    return thing;
}

}
```

1 Edit_
I changed the "Exception" into "JAXBException" because i need to handle that, and it says that the NPE is given by this command: `String data = dataDue.get(0).getThing();` plus my console logs show that wrapper = null which isn't right (it should cointain my Item objects). **So my real problem is that I don't know why wrapper is empty**

I was having this problem before (used my log to find it) but then I tought I got another problem because console logs I put after `ItemListWrapper wrapper = (ItemListWrapper) um.unmarshal(file);` dindn't show up anymore.

2nd Edit_
NOTE!: this is stacktrace that says `ItemListWrapper wrapper = (ItemListWrapper) um.unmarshal(file);`is responsible for the NPE

```html
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:873)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$1(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Lister$CollectionLister.addToPack(Lister.java:289)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Lister$CollectionLister.addToPack(Lister.java:253)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Scope.add(Scope.java:106)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty$ReceiverImpl.receive(ArrayERProperty.java:198)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.endElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:597)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.endElement(SAXConnector.java:165)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:610)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1784)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2969)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:113)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:507)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:867)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:796)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:142)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1216)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:644)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:243)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:214)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:157)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:162)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:171)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:189)
    at application.Main.loadPersonDataFromFile(Main.java:196)
    at application.Main.initRoot(Main.java:83)
    at application.Main.start(Main.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:187)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application application.Main
```

Comment: Post your stacktrace.

Comment: Don't suppress the stack trace (for one thing it will tell you the line number where the exception occurs, instead of you having to clutter your code with logging statements). Include the entire stack trace in the question (format it as code).

Comment: `// catches ANY exception` is almost _always_ a bad idea, and I would reject it during a code review in my team.

Comment: Since I edited my post, I ran it again some times and now it gives the error it gave me when I first posted it, now the stacktrace says that the exception is being thrown by `ItemListWrapper wrapper = (ItemListWrapper)`, I don't know why because I didn't really touch it

Comment: Looks unrelated to javafx - make the data access/read work in isolation first, then move in to doing it in ui context

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand, you mean don't create the Unmarshaller object from JAXBContext?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
 unmarshaller.setClassesToBeBound(ItemListWrapper.class);
```

Comment: says setClassToBeBound is undefined for Unmarshaller type